# How do i color my logs as i am storing them in a html file using layout in logback

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j, logback

I am using logback to log my logs in a html file. I used the color code in layout but as expected they dont work for files. any one have any idea how to do this for html file. this is how my appender looks -

```
<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator class="com.hotwaxmedia.logger.ThreadNameBasedDiscriminator"/>
    <sift>
        <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>runtime/logs/app-${threadName}.html</file>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>&lt;div class=&quot;%p&quot;&gt;%d \(${threadName}\) [%logger{0} : %-5level] %msg%n%rEx&lt;/div&gt;</pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need JNSI jar for above task. Check :

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#coloring